# How to search for nearest picnic-tables and benches in openstreetmap?

Tags: search, openstreetmap

I recently moved to a new city. Now I'd like to find `leisure=picnic_table` and `amenity=bench` close to my new flat. What is the typical way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical way is to use the overpass API via http://overpass-turbo.eu/

Another way would be to use OSMAnd if you have Android and prefer a mobile & offline solution. There you can easily specify an additional POI layer with your (custom) interests.

Comment: With overpass turbo, just browse to your area, open the wizard, type `leisure=picnic_table or amenity=bench` (note the *or*) and hit run.